# How to test if a C function is linkable

Tags: c, gcc, linker, libraries

I just discovered a missing function in one C API I use (it compiles but it doesn't link). I wanted to test the entire set of API functions. The idea was to keep things simple such as:

```
include <myapi.h>
void main(void) {
  func1;
  func2;
  ...
}
```

But this compiles and links fine because the compiler (gcc) optimizes away the unused function pointers. If I use func1() instead, I get a linker error if that function is indeed missing. But all the function calls are complex and it would take days to write explicit parameters for all of them.

I could use nm to query the libraries, but first it's a whole set of .so files and second it probably depends on #defines in the API header.

Is there a simple syntax I can use in a C file ? Or maybe just an (un)optimization option for gcc ?

Comment: Try to recompile with gcc `-O0` it should disable all optimizations

Comment: Very unclear question. Could you be a lot more specific and give the actual use case and motivation. I don't even understand exactly what "missing function in an API" means, given that an API is a documented set of public functions, etc. So please **edit your question** to improve it and motivate it. Be a lot more specific and concrete.

Comment: What is the practical use? Do you want to take all C functions from the Standard and check if your Compiler supports them? That is a lot of work. Why not ask the writer of the Compiler what the Compiler supports and what are the limitations?

Comment: Put another way: I want to find all functions which are documented, present in the header file but missing from the lib files (due to error from the packagers). I don't have the source code of the lib files.

Comment: Don't comment your question, but please *edit* it. And please *be a lot more concrete or specific*. What is the actual library you are concerned about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible workaround could be to use function pointers to fake usage:

```
include <myapi.h>
typedef void Func_T(void);  // Function type for easier handling
Func_T * volatile Func;  // Function pointer where functions are stored
/* Macro to do the assignment */
#define TEST(f)  Func = (Func_T*)f
int main(void) {
    TEST(func1);
    TEST(func2);
    ...
}
```

Linker might still remove the functions, but it's worth the try.

Compilers often offer attributes or pragmas to force keeping symbol. It might be useful for keeping `Func` if linker tries to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Your very unclear question mentions `.so` files (but does not mention any operating system) and `nm`. So I am guessing you are on Linux, and my answer is specific to Linux. I don't understand if you want to work at compile&build-time or at run time.</sup>

Given a shared object `/some/path/to/foo.so` you could use the [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) functions to find out (at runtime) if that shared object defines a given symbol.  But be aware that in [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) files symbols are *nearly* untyped (e.g. you cannot know the signature of some function in an ELF shared object from its name, without having some C header file declaring it).

Alternatively you might have a more complex [software build](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_build) procedure (e.g. by adding ad-hoc rules to your [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile)). Remember that you could use [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) techniques and have some specialized C code generator in your build. If your software is complex enough (e.g. worth spending weeks on such tools) you might even customize the GCC compiler using [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (or write your own GCC plugin).

Notice that some header files (for a given library) may define a function as `inline` or may define a macro with arguments for it (for example, see [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html), part of POSIX API; `WIFEXITED` is practically a macro). In both cases, that function won't be a symbol of the ELF shared library but can be used from source code properly using that library (and correctly [`#include`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive)-ing the appropriate headers). In other words, an [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) is not the same as a set of ELF symbols.

Read also Drepper's [*Good Practices in Library Design, Implementation, and Maintenance*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/goodpractice.pdf) and [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) and D.Wheeler [Program Library HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/).

At last, the compiler is not able to optimize if you add some code depending on conditions which are known to be always false (read about [opaque predicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_predicate)), e.g.

```
int main(int argc, char**argv) {
   // in practice, all the tests above are false,
   // but the compiler is not clever enough to optimize
   if (getpid()==0) funct1(); // always false
   if (argc<0) funct2(); //always false
   if (argv[0][0]==(char)0) funct3(); //always false
   /// etc
```

In case the signature of the functions require some arguments, you could simply test their address:

```
    extern void func1(int); // actually, in some included header
    if (argv[0]==NULL || (void*)func1 == NULL 
        || (void*)func1 == (void*)3) abort();
```

<sup>(I believe that the C standards allow the compiler to optimize `(void*)func1 == NULL` -as always false- but it won't optimize `(void*)func1 == (void*)3`  which in *practice* is always false on Linux...)</sup>

but again, an API is more than a set of ELF symbols, and an API "function" can actually be `inline` or a macro. You might be interested by [weak symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol).

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but I wrote a python script that takes a function signature and tests if it links..

see here https://gist.github.com/Kreijstal/b4a7528245c00625f80cf31fe38e9829

I'll post it here.

```py
import subprocess
import tempfile
import os
import sys

def test_link(function_signature, flags):
    function_name = function_signature.split('(')[0].split()[-1].strip()
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.c', mode='w') as temp_file:
        test_code = f'''
#include <stdio.h>

{function_signature}

int main() {{
    // Using the function address to bypass direct function call
    void *ptr = (void*){function_name};
    return 0;
}}
'''
        temp_file.write(test_code)
        temp_file_path = temp_file.name

    compile_command = f'gcc {temp_file_path} {" ".join(flags)} -o {temp_file.name}.out'
    try:
        subprocess.check_output(compile_command, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        result_message = "Linking succeeded."
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        result_message = "Linking failed. Error:\n" + e.output.decode('utf-8')

    # Clean up
    os.remove(temp_file_path)
    out_path = f'{temp_file.name}.out'
    if os.path.exists(out_path):
        os.remove(out_path)

    return result_message

def main():
    if '--' in sys.argv:
        split_index = sys.argv.index('--')
        function_signature = sys.argv[1]
        flags = sys.argv[split_index+1:]
    else:
        print("Usage: canlink.py \"function signature\" -- [flags]")
        sys.exit(1)

    result = test_link(function_signature, flags)
    print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And you use it like this:

```
python canlink.py "void* XextAddDisplay(void*, void*, void*, void*, int, void*);" -- -L. -lXext
```

It makes for nice one liners.